# Why am I getting vector iterators incompatible?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm doing the following and getting that debug error:

```
AguiWidgetBase* AguiWidgetContainer::recursiveGetWidgetUnderMouse(
    AguiWidgetBase* root, const AguiMouseEventArgs &mouse)
{

    AguiWidgetBase* currentNode = root;
    bool foundsomething = true;

    while(foundsomething)
    {
        foundsomething = false;
        if(currentNode->getChildCntrolCount() > 0)
            for (std::vector<AguiWidgetBase*>::const_reverse_iterator rit =
                    currentNode->getChildRBeginIterator();
                rit < currentNode->getChildREndIterator(); ++rit) 
            { 
                if(!foundsomething)
                    if ((*rit)->intersectionWithPoint(mouse.getPosition())) 
                    { 
                        foundsomething = true;
                        currentNode = *rit;
                    } 

                } 
            }
            return currentNode;
        }

    // ...
```

It fails after currentNode becomes a pointer to a child of root, and crashes on the for.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning the end position which is being checked by your iterator.

2 comments:

1. Put the brackets around your `if` statements.  You're allowed not to do it but it makes the code more readable if you do and reminds you to indent.
2. add a break statement to the inner `if` so that you don't need to continue traversing the vector.  That will accomplish exactly what you want without the extra variable and variable check.

Comment: @Milo - see my edit.  Add a break statement in the inner if statement so that you short circuit your for loop.  However, don't reassign the iterator to begin with.  If you feel you must, use a different variable!